# How to run Redis on docker with a different configuration file?

Tags: redis, docker, dockerfile

I would like to set a password on my Redis server running on docker. I have followed the instcruction on https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/redis/:

1.I have created a folder with a Dockerfile containing:

```
FROM redis  
COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf  
CMD [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]
```

2.I have added a redis.conf file with:

```
requirepass thepassword
```

3.I built the image using:

```
docker build -t ouruser/redis .
```

4.I started the container:

```
docker run --name my-redis -p 0.0.0.0:6379:6379 -d ouruser/redis redis-server --appendonly yes
```

The redis server does not have any password ! I do not understand why.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The run command:

```
docker run --name my-redis -p 0.0.0.0:6379:6379 -d ouruser/redis redis-server --appendonly yes
```

Overrides the CMD defined in the Dockerfile with `redis-server --appendonly yes`, so your conf file will be being ignored. Just add the path to the conf file into your run command:

```
docker run --name my-redis -p 0.0.0.0:6379:6379 -d ouruser/redis redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf --appendonly yes
```

Alternatively, set up an entrypoint script or add `--appendonly yes` to the CMD instruction.